# How to merge different "event types" in Google Data Studio stacked bar chart visualization?

Tags: data-visualization, bar-chart, visualization, looker-studio, stacked-bar-chart

Sample Data:

```
video_id    video_num   event   starting_time   length_sec
3ofhi23r2   1           stall   3:15:00         81
3ofhi23r2   1           load    3:16:21         71
3ofhi23r2   2           load    3:17:31         10
3ofhi23r2   3           stall   3:17:41         10
3ofhi23r2   3           load    3:17:51         10
3ofhi23r2   4           stall   3:18:01         10
3ofhi23r2   4           load    3:18:11         10
3ofhi23r2   4           stall   3:18:21         10
3ofhi23r2   4           load    3:18:31         10
```

The parameters I've tried setting:

- date range dimension: `starting_time`
- dimension: `video_id`, `event_type`
- breakdown dimension: `video_num`
- metric: `SUM(length_sec)` [not sure how to change aggregation]
- sort: `video_num` ASC, `video_num` ASC

Actual Result:
[image]

Data Studio Report:
https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/9143b28e-58f0-43f8-9be1-a87a27fc7a8d

Instead, I want each stall event and load event per `video_num` to be on the same bar. Ideally, each stall colour and each load colour should be the same. I want the `starting_time` to appear on the x-axis. My expected result should be something like follows (not exact):

[image: ![enter image description here]

I believe a similar visualization may be able to be achieved via an Area Chart, so I'm open to getting help with that kind of solution too.

I've also seen similar visualizations in the Answers section of this thread:
[Is this timeline chart visualization possible in Google Data Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52709535/is-this-timeline-chart-visualization-possible-in-google-data-studio)

Comment: A (vertical) stacked bar chart should work. The breakdown dimension has to be the `item_no`. And the sorting would by `id` and as 2nd sorting `item_no`. For having minutes on the axis use as metric a field with the formula `SUM(length_sec)/60`